# Assembly language. NASM caculator

Tags: assembly, nasm

The code compiles and runs. For some reason though it will only let me input one number my symbol to perform the calculation and then closes before I can put in another number. I'm trying to get the programs to output as the following

```
3
+
2
= 
5
```

This is my NASM code so far:

```
segment .data
  num1: db 4
  num2: db 4
  button: db 2

        segment .bss


        segment .text
         global  asm_main

        asm_main:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
```

----------- **CODE STARTS HERE** -----------------

```
  call read_int
    mov DWORD[num1], eax

    call read_char
    mov DWORD[button], edx

    call read_int
    mov DWORD[num2], eax

    cmp DWORD[button], '+'
    jne addition

    cmp DWORD[button], '-'
    je subtraction

    cmp DWORD[button], '*'
    je multiplication

    cmp DWORD[button], '/'
    je division

    cmp DWORD[button], '%'
    je modulus

    addition:
    mov eax, DWORD[num1]
    add eax, DWORD[num2]
    call print_int
    jmp end

    subtraction:
    jmp end
    multiplication:
    jmp end
    division:
    jmp end
    modulus:
    jmp end

   end:
```

Comment: You're not showing all the code, e.g. `read_char`. One problem is your use of DWORD with `button`, which you have declared as two bytes.

Comment: Actually it's even worse, `db 2` does **not** define two bytes, it's just one byte with value `2`. You want `dd` for dwords.

Comment: what do you mean by i'm not showing all the code?

Comment: Do I need to make all my variable dd?

Comment: If you want to load and store dwords without overlapping into other storage, then yes.  Or better, put them in `.bss` with `resd 1` because you don't care about the initial value.